# Turtle module register shape problem in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was trying to create a Turtle project which looks as follows:

```
def randcol():
    hex=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","a","b","c","d","e","f"]
    cur="#"
    for _ in range(6):
        cur+=(choice(hex))
    return cur

def _setup():
    import turtle as t
    global t
    t.register_shape("circ.gif")
    from random import choice
    global choice
    from time import sleep
    global sleep

def _main():
    wn=t.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor((randcol()))
    ck=t.Turtle()
    ck.fillcolor((randcol()))
    ck.shape("circ.gif")
    ck.shapesize(40,50)
    ck.penup()
    ck.setpos(0,0)
    while running:
        wn.mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    _setup()
    global running=True
    _main()
```

However, the code gives absolutely no errors and does not work as expected.

I registered an image "circ.gif" and tried to use it. But it did not show. I have ensured that the file is in the same directory and with gif extension.
Here is the "circ.gif" file:

```
GIF89a���������,-�-.�;<�<=�JK�KL�YZ�Z[�hi�ij�wx�wy��������������������!�,��� '�di�h��l�p,�tm�x��|���pH,�Ȥr�l:�ШtJ�Z�جv��z��xL.���z�n���|N����~������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
H���*\Ȱ�Ç#J�H��ŋ3j�ȱ�Ǐ C�I��ɓ(S��\ɲ�˗0cʜI��͛8s��ɳ�ϟ@�
J��ѣH�*]ʴ�ӧP�J�J��իX�j�ʵ�ׯ`ÊK��ٳhӪ]˶�۷p�ʝK��ݻx���˷�߿�L���È+^̸��ǐ#K�L���˘3k�̹��ϠC�M���ӨS�^ͺ��װc˞M���۸s��ͻ����N����ȓ+_μ���УK�N����سk�ν����ËO�����ӫ_Ͼ�����˟O��������Ͽ���(�h�&����6��F(�Vh�f��v�� �(�$�h�(���,���0�(�4�h�8��<���@)�Di�H&��L6��PF)�TVi�Xf��\v��`�)�d�i�h���l���p�)�t�i�x�)|�Az���8�����6�(� ��H����1(  ���*ꨑ:��j�
x:꫰�*80��:�*���믌����J�
���*�������������Ұ�
d+
�@�ݮ`����閐��«ﾎ ��j��l0�
L�A�H`��G̀y
�o�L�uj�@� g�q��lr�@���z������-�l3��.��3�9��A�?�3g��F7-rZVp��T���Qj@t�\���@�����L��+���������$Sӭ7��+�[�-8��Aރ'N�I�(���۷������cjc������礓[��1V^���
�.��4������/�����
��o�¯X�����7/���?<��j.��c���x�����㗯~��~����j�S�����[�������P�G@�A�+��@�*�����6h�| ��>�y
Z�?� ����   O����,̠T���̏gC*`@��# �  1�)�O
�C�g�L����(����1�m�D�,q�6t�}���N�>,�
�8����]L��Ḑst����<�m�р��@�n�1�{��H!�1=�c#m���q�G��w�IB�琝�!��P
Q9��xhJV�<Zl%5y�
�r���%o��V�%wv    L!���,� ���(ӊ��$����=��v����1;��
��n�������E;b��D�u�(&�:άg��s�����?�X���r�=�r���2:�l�#��F�����I�E)�P�0�r�1@t�#*�9�,����p�ԃ�\I_�Ó.G�4-`G�#М����ɧOc�J��t�,<�M����Г�'<�r\
U.��U-�R��Ь���y�W3(Ֆ�����Y���tu��+q���{'�tU P��Ѽ�8������
v}m���t���\���u8x�,��:��j6~�    �g�GX�v��K�o�Z�9�7�mm�&������m��Y�dv����o~\�    �7�-�����*Wz�}n�#Z�2�����v����rwz��Mu�������e�yu���2o��i�{�_��w��{-{�{<����]}o��W��݀m3�cn�i��#a�HxS�m.���y�äUA���8��q�=��{n��u1���xn4�MJo���ǐ��o���7.��*a%�����VO�i��n��5��lc�o���7I.s�l*����iLf�v+��d8NO��3/ז�F�j]4���Ä>��yc�D,��q���
2Kb���/�E�Ƴ�6X����PG�ȱ������lz���a}�Q/�Դ�����\c���A���%k��o�y�{uf�z���p�mf��9��6���)kX�Ζ�-�];'��U��3�t�������g���{Tl�N��m�����������s^�#���V8t~l�'��ˆtvЭ�uK�ָv8�l�O��6��m��;���t���fg�ÎyyH��|�ⴖ�v-�pc'�ж�w�p�G��޴�yy4��\��<Ds�.MZ+}<(���uI[�;��HN;=>�Vs�m�l_���:�)��O9����������I���N��c����    / �w�hT;���h^Ɯ׏�yy9���?���z�>��oP��{Q\�t�틋y�]��'P���
���_��+d-_��W���M����f_�ڇ��y���֏�����I4z�@�j?c�"
�_/�����p�~7b�g�,��=�H%�>B�>e�3���DU\W#Pv��#i�P ��:6�d6Ycy��C���t&8$K�L�}R�,�F_�%@s[t��$?8I �PR�y4iR;HAL�&���3�%���G&%3B�҅g�-�=�8h'ex<  P}qr/@8;�0���<W(��|x.w80�kSPbX�%���=��@ �І/s܂�G�0�T/p`�H��; ��h��v��*��~���r��@�苼���'Cx�ʸ��،�����8��X��x�ؘ�ڸ��؍�����8��X��x�蘎긎�؎�����8��X��x����؏���9�Y�y���
��ِ��9�Y�y�����ّ� �"9�$Y�&y�(��*��,ْ.�0�29�4Y�6y�8��:��<ٓ>�@�B9�DY�Fy�H��J��LٔN�P�R9�TY�Vy��X��Z��\ٕ^�`�b9�dY�fy�h��j��lٖn�p�r9�tY�vy�x��z��|ٗ~���9��Y��y��������٘����9��Y��y��������ٙ����9��Y��y��������ٚ����9��Y��y��������ٛ�����9��Y��y�ș�ʹ��ٜ�����9��Y��y�ؙ�ڹ��ٝ�����9��Y��y�虞깞�ٞ�����9��Y��y����ٟ����:�Z�z���
��ڠ��:�Z�z�����ڡ� �":�$Z�&z�(��*��,ڢ.�0�2:�4Z�6z�8��:��<ڣ>�@�B:�DZ�Fz�H��J��LڤN�P�R:�TZ�Vz�X��Z��\ڥ^�`�b:�dZ�fz�h��j��lڦn�p�r:�tZ�vz�x��z��|ڧ~���:��Z��z��������ڨ����:��Z��z��������ک����:��Z��z���������ڪ����:��Z��z��������ګ�����:��Z��z�Ț�ʺ��ڬ�����:��Z��z�ؚ�ں��ڭ�����:��Z��z�蚮꺮�ڮ�����:��Z��z����گ���!;
```

Comment: why would you post an ascii encoding of the gif file?  You have certainly made some odd choices in my opinion but it looks like the only thing that is actually wrong is towards the end.  `global running=True` will definitely cause a syntax error.  You need to make the global declaration before you can assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can achieve your goal using the approach you've chosen.  Consider:

```
ck.shape("circ.gif")
ck.shapesize(40,50)
```

A turtle cursor shape loaded from a file doesn't conform to the `shapesize()` method.  I.e. it'll remain as is and not stretch.  This only works for `Shape` based turtle cursors.  Also, this code:

```
while running:
    wn.mainloop()
```

will bring your code to a standstill.  It turns control over to tkinter's event loop and there are no events defined that return control to your program.

Here's my rework of your program that I believe gets you a bit closer to your end objective:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import choices

HEX_CHARACTERS = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

def randcol():
    return "#" + ''.join(choices(HEX_CHARACTERS, k=6))

screen = None
turtle = None

def _setup():
    global screen, turtle

    screen = Screen()

    turtle = Turtle()
    turtle.shape('circle')
    turtle.shapesize(10, 25)

    _main()

    screen.mainloop()

def _main():
    screen.bgcolor(randcol())

    turtle.color(randcol())

    screen.ontimer(_main, 1000)  # 1 second in miliseconds

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _setup()
```

Comment: But the circle is not a circle but just a polygon...

Comment: @Alphega, read about turtle's `Shape` class.  In addition to built-in shapes and images,  can define a turtle cursor shape by supplying the positions that make up a polygon.  Being a shape, you will be able to arbitrarily streatch and rotate them, unlike images.